# import com.oracle.cie.common.ui.gui.AppManager causes ANT build error

Tags: java, oracle, ant

I have a Java 1.7 web application that I need to use an AppManager for.

It seems to work fine when I run it locally.  However, when I try to build it using an ANT script - I get a package does not exist error.

Here is my code...

```
import com.oracle.cie.common.ui.gui.AppManager;

Properties properties = new Properties();

    try {
        properties.load(AppManager.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("build.properties"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is the error I get when I try to build it using ANT...

```
error: package com.oracle.cie.common.ui.gui does not exist
[javac] import com.oracle.cie.common.ui.gui.AppManager;
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package name suggests this class comes from a jar bundled with one of Oracle's products. Just in case, I searched [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3A%22com.oracle.cie.common.ui.gui.AppManager%22) and confirmed that this is not a class belonging to a well known open source jar.

You state that this is "running locally". Does this mean that an IDE like Eclipse is able to compile your code? Assuming that is the case I would suggest you take a peek into the IDE settings and revise the 3rd party jars used. (For example Eclipse frequently creates a file within the project called ".classpath" that lists all the compile time jar dependencies).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yep.  It runs locally on an Eclipse IDE.  I think this gets me a bit further.  Thanks.